# MySQL replication: slave is not getting data from master

Tags: mysql, replication

My problem is that all setup is done for MySQL replication but the slave is unable to sync the master's data. To understand I am sharing link below; please visit.

```
mysql>  SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.10.110
                  Master_User: slaveuser
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000033
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 402
               Relay_Log_File: VoltyLinux-relay-bin.000046
                Relay_Log_Pos: 317
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000033
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: replica
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 402
              Relay_Log_Space: 692
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: f1739fcc-0d2d-11e6-a8cc-c03fd56585b5
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 60
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/q/36929641/2644613

Comment: Just to clarify: with "sync" you mean that changes on master are not propagated to the slave, right? What are the `server_id`s  of the servers? (run: `show global variables like 'server_id'` on both the slave and the master). Please also include the master status from the master host. Do you have any replication filters enabled?

Answer (score 0):

From your `Show slave status \G` output, the following things can be understood:

1. `Slave_IO_Running: Yes` It means, Input Output thread is running - this thread is responsible for downloading data (binlog) from master server to slave server.
2. `Slave_SQL_Running: Yes` It means, SQL thread is running - this thread is responsible for executing SQL from relay log (from binlog).
3. `Read_Master_Log_Pos: 402`, `Exec_Master_Log_Pos = 402`, It means, the IO thread reading from the binary log position 402 and the SQL thread executing the same query.
4. `Seconds_Behind_Master: 0` It means, both the master and slave is in sync and slave is in up-to the point, no delay.
5. `Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates.` It means slave is up to the point.

It seems, slave is getting data from master and there is no issues in your settings.

**FYI:**

1. Run the `Show Slave Status \G` command continuously, you will see the following variable values will change, every time.

> ```
> Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000033
> Read_Master_Log_Pos: 402
> Relay_Log_File: VoltyLinux-relay-bin.000046
> Relay_Log_Pos: 317
> Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 402
> Relay_Log_Space: 692
> ```

In case, if your slave stopped getting data from master server, you will see the `No` value for `Slave_IO Running` variable in your `Show Slave Status \G` command output as follows.

```
Slave_IO_Running: NO
```

I hope this answer will help you. Thanks.

Comment: "change every time"?  I don't think so.

Comment: @RickJames If master data replicated to slave, the values will change. However, we can define the maximum size limit for log files (binary log & relay log), once the max limit reached, log files names will change. I tried to answer in simple language, so may be few things change a bit. Thank you.

Comment: In non-busy systems, Log_files may change only once a week.  A busy system might see them change once an hour.  But _not_ "every time you run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`".

Comment: Simple way just create a test database on master server and see if it got created on slave server (assuming no time lagging).